# How to Connect to Database SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: laravel

I got this error when i tried to connect to my database:

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select `active_template` from `general_settings` limit 1)

I'm new to laravel so i'm sorry if it's a common question because i try to find the solution and see similar problems but not exactly the same.

I tried to change my .env files and use no pass for the db and restart the server but it is still getting the same error. Here's what my env files look like:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=production
APP_KEY=base64:xxx
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database123
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

what should i do? thankyou

Comment: try to add Db information between ''
DB_DATABASE='xxx'
DB_USERNAME='xxxx'
DB_PASSWORD='xxxxx'

Answer (score 0):

Try to make another MySQL user, and grant all privileges to **ONLY** that database. Mostly root user is denied from shared hosting since i check your APP_ENV is on production.

Hope this helpful

https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-create-new-mysql-user-account-grant-privileges

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.like below:

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException
 SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = finotech and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

at the first check your .env file in project.
I checked:

```
 APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:80
```

also this parameters:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306 
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root 
DB_PASSWORD=
```

at the final I tried with this command line in the root of laravel project in cmd.

```
php artisan route:cache
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan optimize
```

then run you command,php artisan migrate, may it helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, default password for the root user is `password`. So kindly update the value of environment variable `DB_PASSWORD` e.g.

```
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

Answer (score -1):

try `php artisan config:cache` and `php artisan cache:clear` after changing your .env file

Comment: i tried this and get the same feedback as my initial problem